# SQL query with a concatenated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL isn't that strong, I'll admit...but my query looks similar to below in MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT p.Product_ID as ID,
      (p.Product_Number + ' - ' +  p.Product_Name) as Name 
FROM Product p;
```

I'm wondering, is it possible to do a query on that concatenated column? Or would I have to use two `WHERE` clauses and combine them with an `AND`?

Comment: you concatenate in the where clause

Comment: There is a `+` missing in front of `p.Product_Name`.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I don't think you concatenate in the where clause.... WHERE p.Product_Number = 1 AND p.Product_Name = 'Peanuts'

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer Thanks for that, I was modifying the query I had. Fixed!

Comment: @sam I'm pretty sure you can.

Comment: Just because you can concatenate strings in the where clause doesn't mean you should. It causes your query to be nonSARGable and it can't utilize indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the expression in your where clause. Like this:

```
SELECT p.Product_ID as ID, (p.Product_Number + ' - ' + p.Product_Name) as Name 
FROM Product p
WHERE (p.Product_Number + ' - ' + p.Product_Name) = '123 - Name';
```

Comment: You might have some data conversion to deal with.  More concise to query on each column IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concatenation in the `WHERE` clause or use `CONCAT()` function if your server support it:

```
    SELECT p.Product_ID as ID,
      (p.Product_Number + ' - ' + p.Product_Name) as Name 
     FROM Product p
    where
     p.Product_Number + ' - ' + p.Product_Name = 'blah' ;
```

or

```
    SELECT p.Product_ID as ID,
      concat(p.Product_Number,' - ' ,p.Product_Name) as Name 
     FROM Product p
    where
       concat(p.Product_Number,' - ' ,p.Product_Name) = 'blah' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

So far the other answers will work but they are not going to scale well at all because they are nonSARGable. That means no indexing would help these queries because it has to do the string concatenation for every single row in the table to know if it is a valid row or not. It would be FAR better from a performance perspective to use two predicates. It also makes your query a lot more legible in my opinion.

Here is the best way from a performance standpoint to do this.

```
SELECT p.Product_ID as ID
    , p.Product_Number + ' - ' + p.Product_Name as Name 
FROM Product p
WHERE p.Product_Number = '123'
    AND p.Product_Name = 'Name';
```